# Delay in changing connection status of Multipeer connectivity once the devices are disconnected from each other

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I got stuck with the MPC framework. When two devices are connected, the connection status is shown as connected. However, the console keeps giving an error of connection fails while data of two devices is in sync . The error is `[ViceroyTrace] [ICE][ERROR]    Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(801A0016).`

Also, when I put a device to sleep, the console gives the log of `lost Peer: <MCPeerID: 0x608000002f60 DisplayName = iPAD>` but the connection status of the device takes around 6s or more to change from connected to disconnected.

Here are the codes in MPC

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

var peerMS: MasterSlave?

protocol MPCDelegate {
    func connectionChanged(handler: MPCHandler, connectedDevices: [String])
}



class MPCHandler: NSObject{
    private let serviceType = "iOS-mpc"
    private let myPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    private let advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser
    let session: MCSession
    let browser: MCBrowserViewController
    let autoBrowser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser
    var delegate: MPCDelegate?

    override init(){

    self.session = MCSession(peer: self.myPeerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
    self.advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: myPeerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: serviceType)
    self.browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: serviceType, session: self.session)
    self.autoBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: myPeerID, serviceType: serviceType)

    super.init()

    self.session.delegate = self
    self.advertiser.delegate = self
    self.advertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()
    self.browser.delegate = self
    self.autoBrowser.delegate = self
    self.autoBrowser.startBrowsingForPeers()
}

deinit {
    self.autoBrowser.stopBrowsingForPeers()
    self.advertiser.stopAdvertisingPeer()
}


func send(d: [NSDictionary]){
    NSLog("%@", "Send data: \(d) to \(session.connectedPeers.count) peers")

    if session.connectedPeers.count > 0{
        do {
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: d)
            try self.session.send(data, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
        } catch {
            NSLog("%@", "Error for sending data: \(error)")
        }
     }
   }


 }
extension MPCHandler: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate{
  func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser,    didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: Error) {
    NSLog("%@", "didNotStartAdvertisingPeer: \(error)")
}



func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data?, invitationHandler: @escaping (Bool, MCSession?) -> Void) {
    NSLog("%@", "didReceiveInvitationFromPeer: \(peerID)")
    invitationHandler(true, self.session)
}

}


extension MPCHandler: MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate{
func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    //self.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    //self.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }


}

extension MPCHandler: MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate{
func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, didNotStartBrowsingForPeers error: Error) {
    NSLog("%@","didNotStartBrowsingForPeers: \(error)")
}



func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
    NSLog("%@","found Peer: \(peerID)")
    NSLog("%@", "invite Peer: \(peerID)")
    autoBrowser.invitePeer(peerID, to: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 3)
}

func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    NSLog("%@", "lost Peer: \(peerID)")
}
}



extension MPCHandler: MCSessionDelegate{
func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    NSLog("%@", "peer: \(peerID) didChangeState: \(state)")
    self.delegate?.connectionChanged(handler: self, connectedDevices: session.connectedPeers.map{$0.displayName})

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "broadcastMaster"), object:  nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "peerChange"), object: nil)

    }






}


func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    NSLog("%@", "didReceive: \(data)")


    if var dict: [NSDictionary] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [NSDictionary]{
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let d = dict.removeFirst()

        switch d.value(forKey: "action") as! String {

        case appDelegate.numberDataController.syncNumCMD:
            appDelegate.numberDataController.syncNumFromDictionary(d: dict.first!)

        default: break
        }


    }
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    NSLog("%@", "didReceiveStream")
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
    NSLog("%@", "didStartReceivingResourceWithName")
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL, withError error: Error?) {
    NSLog("%@", "didFinishReceivingResourceWithName")
}
}
```

The connection status is shown as "connected" when two devices are in connection
[image]

When the devices are disconnected, it takes around 6 seconds to change the status
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on fixing these two problems? Thanks in advance!